AWS Glue job keeps running but logs stop appearing after a few lines in CloudWatch
When i run a Glue job, sometimes logs appear in CloudWatch, but it frequently happens that logs do not appear in CloudWatch then i have to restart the whole process.
In the console, job shows running.
It keeps running for over 40 mins.
Logs start, a few lines appear and then no logs appear.
The job usually gets over in less than 7 mins and all the logs are also displayed in case of both failure and success.
Why do the logs stop appearing after a few lines sometimes even though job keeps showing 'running'?
